# How to recover files from a DVD?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, file-recovery

I backed up some files on a DVD-R but now the files are gone and Windows shows the DVD as empty. How is that possible? I don't remember losing files like that since the days of 5 1/4 inch floppies...

I might have burned the disk in "usb mode" (which I never do) but I'm sure the files were there because I distinctly remember pulling the tray out, than inserting it back in and checking that the files were there.

I kept the disk in the drive for a while, mostly working in Linux (the machine is a dual boot), I booted up in Windows, got an error message that Windows needs to run check disk due to file corruption (Lixus writes some files to a NTFS partition Windows uses and I think Windows got confused), check disk ran, fixed some errors and when I booted up the machine and looked at the files they were gone.

I don't know if check disk had anything to do with it but what are my options here?

I'm running Piriform Recuva at the moment - It found a bunch of deleted files on the DVD, but I'm suspicious of the results. For one the file sizes on some of the files do not look right and second the dates on some of those files go back over a year.

What could have happened? What can I do to get my files back? (I have some of them and it's not the end of the world if I don't get them all, but I want to get them back if possible).

Comment: I burned it maybe a month ago. The disk came from a pack of blank DVDs I bought a bunch of years ago, but never had any issues with until now.

Comment: Did you verify that the files were successfully written in the first place? I've made the mistake where I've dragged files into the burn queue and forgotten to actually write them.